# Principled BSDF Emission Issues

Tags: node-editor

I've been following Blender Guru's beginner tutorial on YouTube (Part 5, Level 2), and after rendering, I'm unsure how it happened but the Emission in the Principled BSDF node seems to be permanently activated and there seems to be no way to disable it. It was not like this before the render and I am 99.99% sure I have my nodes set up exactly like his own (see Part 5, Level 2 for Blender Guru's complete node setup).

TL;DR: Emission in Principled BSDF suddenly acting strange, any way to solve this?

Comment: if you don't want any Emission, choose a black color. Also, there will be a Emission Strength in the Principled of the next Blender.

Comment: I've tried to set the Emission to black, but that only makes the donut glow black instead.